# newbie nodejs quest - passing data between routes/files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new in node.js and I have a headache cause I can't get how to pass data between files/routes in node.js

My file structure looks like this (very simple popular structure):

```
ROUTES (folder)
--form.js
--test.js

VIEWS (folder)
--form.ejs
--test.ejs

index.js
package.json
```

index.js file (standard express app file):

```
var express = require('express');
var body_parser = require('body-parser');

var form = require('./routes/form.js');
var test = require('./routes/test.js');

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use('/', form);
app.use('/test', test);

var port = 3700;
var server_listen_on = app.listen(port, function()
{
    console.log('Server is listening on port: ' + port);
});
```

form.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>pole</title>

</head>
<body>

Hi! Put some web address here:</br>

<form action="/post" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="address">
    <input type="submit" value="ENTER OR CLICK HERE">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

test.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>

</head>
<body>

    The page you fill in:<br>
    <%= target %><br>
    Let us see how it looks like:<br>


</body>
</html>
```

form.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var body_parser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next)
{
    res.render('form'); // this is rendering our form - as a start page
});

router.post('/post', function(req, res, next)
{
    var data = req.body.address; // user fill the form (test.ejs file)
    res.render('test', {target : req.body.address}); // we grab the data that user put in the form and render test page that will show this data
    module.exports.page = data; // now I want to pass it to other js file - test.js
});





var page = function()
{
    console.log('just for test purpose');
};

module.exports = router; // right now module.exports is equal to router (express.router).
// How to pass some more data in it (like above function - page) - something like module.exports = page + router; So I could use page variable in other js file[?]
```

test.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var router = express.Router();

var req_formjs = require('./form.js');

console.log(req_formjs.data); // undefined... [?] how to pass variables from form.js to test.js [?]

router.get('/', function (req, res, next)
{
    request.get(target, function (err, res, body) // putting target in here (as a url) isn't working... [?] how to pass variable from router.post in form.js to router.get in test.js [?]
    {
        if (!err && res.statusCode == 200)
        {
            res.render('test', {content : body}); // second render of test.ejs is not working [?]
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The simpler (answer) the better. Some questions are in the code - for better understanding. If there is any tutorial or similar question asked (I did check and I could not find anything well described) with answer just paste the link, thanks.

**EDIT: let use simpler form for better understanding. Question is how to pass variable to other js file in the simplest mode (without any routes just with module.exports).**

index.js - same

form.js

```
var express = require('express');
var body_parser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();

var preciousData = 'var precious_data - from form.js file';

module.exports =
{
    exportsPreciousData : preciousData,
    router : router
};
```

test.js

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var router = express.Router();

var requireFormjs = require('./form.js');//({exportsPreciousData : exportsPreciousData});


//console.log(requireFormjs.exportsPreciousData); // I guess console.log is faster then module.exports... but

router.get('/', function(req, res, next)
{
    res.render('welcome', {test : requireFormjs.exportsPreciousData});
});

// why this doesn't work - I need to use middleware function - could you provide simple working example?
//(I guessing that even if console.log print data after module.exports machinery I would still need middleware, right?)

module.exports = router;
```

welcome.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>welcome</title>

</head>
<body>

<%= test %>

</body>
</html>
```

... why it's not working (without express everything runs fine)?

Comment: What do you want to do with the `data` if you want to do some processing then call a function where you pass the data to from you router. If you need it for a later request of the user then you need session.

Answer (score 0):

You can export pretty much anything you want to.  If you want to pass the router plus the page function,  you can do something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  router: router,
  page : page
};
```

Coversely, if you're trying to inject something into the required module, you'd expose a function, eg:

```
module.exports = function(options){
   // do something with the options
   return router; // possibly modified by the options
};

// in your requiring file

var formRouter = require('./router')({key: 'value'});
app.use(formRouter);
```

** EDIT after comment **

As for trying to export in the middle of a route handler, as  you're doing in here:

```
router.post('/post', function(req, res, next)
{
    var data = req.body.address; // user fill the form (test.ejs file)
    res.render('test', {target : req.body.address}); // we grab the data that user put in the form and render test page that will show this data
    module.exports.page = data; // now I want to pass it to other js file - test.js
});
```

It really doesn't make sense to do so.  First, modules are only exported once in the life of the running application.  They're essentially a Singleton that gets instantiated the first time on the first `require` statement.  So exporting data later will mean you only have the last post's worth of data as you have written it.  Furthermore, that handler fires potentially many times over the course of your app (every time the post happens).

If you tell us why you want to export that data on every post, I might be able to tell you the best way to solve your actual need.

Comment: The OP set `data` as result of a `post` request (`var data = req.body.address;`)  so this would not really work. Well you could get it work, but it would not make much sense and would result into problems if there are two `post` requests at nearly the same time. Further more it will still be `undefined`  at `console.log(req_formjs.data);`  because the `console.log`  is called before any `post`  request is done.

Comment: Well, sorta.  If you follow all his comments he did ask that, but he *also* asked how to export multiple things (see the end of his form.js file, where he defines a page function then right away asks about exporting router + page).  I was answering that, having completely missed him trying to export in the middle of a middleware function.  Thanks for pointing that out, I'll add commentary about that to my answer.

Comment: In nodejs `module.exports`  is the object that is returned by the `require` statement. So as long as `module.exports` itself is not overwritten then every change done to `module.exports` will be available at every place where the file was required.  So `req_formjs.data` would indeed contain the property added with `module.exports.page = data;`, if the `console.log` is done **after** a `post` has happened. But this doesn't change the fact, that it does not make any sense to use `export` for that purpose.

Comment: I have edited the question - let's work at simpler form - for better understanding and then we will move to more advanced code and answer the question as a whole).

Comment: @t.niese, I think that's what I said in my edit, no?

Comment: Then `[...]They're essentially a Singleton that gets instantiated the first time on the first require statement. So exporting data later won't matter at all.[...]` is somehow miss leading. Because adding to the export later does matter.